# Sublime Text 3: How to install plugins from Github

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext, sublimetext3

How do I install plugins from github for Sublime Text 3? I am trying to install [this](https://github.com/BoundInCode/Display-Functions). What I have done so far is installing `displayfunctions.py` into `Packages/Display-Functions/displayfunctions.py` (I created a new folder `Display-Functions` in the `Packages` folder to hold `displayfuntions.py`). It still doesn't work. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

### This installation flow work for any Sublime-Text 2/3 plugins.

- Quit Sublime
- Go to folder `Packages`:

  - Windows: `%APPDATA%\Sublime Text 3\Packages`
  - OS X: `~/Library/Application\ Support/Sublime\ Text\ 3/Packages`
  - Linux: `~/.config/sublime-text-3/Packages/`
- Run: `git clone https://github.com/BoundInCode/Display-Functions.git`
- Open Sublime and try to use.

Comment: does this integrate with package control? if I later want to remove the package, can I just delete the clone or will that leave null references?

Comment: @rblakeley **Yes** it integrate with Package Control.

Comment: Should the existing ST2 package currently available on Package Control ever be updated to support ST3, you should clone the repository  `Display Functions (Java)`, since that's the name registered in the Package Control channel: `git clone https://github.com/BoundInCode/Display-Functions.git "Display Functions (Java)"`

Comment: @Siddharth Which plugin did you tried install? Did you have any error messages? Also check if this plugin compatible with your ST version.

Comment: In my case, I didnt have to restart Sublime. I just went to folder Packages, and then run git clone command. Thanks @AntonDozortsev

Answer (score 38):

In Sublime Text 3, if you already have [Package Control](https://packagecontrol.io/), but the package isn't showing up in `Install Packages`, *for instance [ChainOfCommand](https://github.com/jisaacks/ChainOfCommand)*, you need to "Add the Repository" to add the package to Package Control, ***only then*** can you install it.

Here's a step-by-step process:

1. In a Web Browser, navigate to your plugin, copy the git url (should end with a `.git`).

   - for ChainOfCommand, this is `https://github.com/jisaacks/ChainOfCommand.git`

   [image: Get the git URL in github]
2. In Sublime, Open Package Control

   [image: Open Package Control from the Preferences Menu]
3. Select `Package Control: Add Repository`

   [image]
4. At the bottom of the Sublime window, an input box will appear. Paste the URL. ***AND REMOVE THE .GIT EXTENSION***;  hit Enter.

   [image: The Add Repo Input Box]

   - Now the Repo has been added to Package Control, it's not installed though
5. Open Package Control again (like in step 2).
6. Select `Package Control: Install Packages`

   [image]
7. Now you should be able to search for, and install the package that had previously been missing, ie ChainOfCommand.

---

### Alternatively, If you have [TortoiseGit](https://tortoisegit.org/), you can do a manual install:

1. Similar to above, go copy the URL (include .git this time).
2. In Sublime, go to Preferences > Browse Packages (This opens the Packages folder).

   [image: Browse Sublime Packages]
3. Right-click on an empty space of the folder > Git Clone

   [image: Git Clone via Tortoise]
4. Because the URL is already on your clipboard, it should automatically appear in the URL of the Git Clone Window. Press OK and Voila, Installed.

Comment: 'install package' command saved me! I kept wondering for close to 30min where that git repo was even after adding it and seeing it appear 3 times in the Package Control User Settings!

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. It includes the in-app way to do this with "Add Repository" as well as the manual option, although it does use TortoiseGit for the manual option, which is Windows only.

Answer (score 4):

For Sublime text 3, I've installed some packages from GitHub like this:

- Install `Package Control`:

  - open console: `View->Show Console` (or <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd>)
  - copy and paste the code from [packagecontrol.io](https://packagecontrol.io/installation) and run (press <kbd>Enter</kbd>)
  - In the console, select `Add repository`
  - Add the GitHub link and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>
  - In console, select 'install package' and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>

You are finished and ready to use the packages.

Update: Thanks @GMunguia for remembering the warning.

Comment: From [Package Control website](https://packagecontrol.io/installation): "Please do not redistribute the install code via another website. It will change with every release. Instead, please link to this page. ".

Answer (score 0):

Since this plugin is available via [Package Control](https://sublime.wbond.net/installation), which I find is the most convenient way to install packages, you should look into installing that. It's a widely supported package manager for Sublime Text 2/3.

Comment: It ain't on PackageControl, atleast not for ST3. :(

Comment: It is not available via Package control.

Answer (score 0):

> Go to `tools` then `command palette...` , then type `package control: install package` and hit enter. after that type the name of the package you want . it is very easy